# Symfony2 unexpected character SwiftMailer

Tags: symfony, twig, swiftmailer

Good day,

I am trying to send an email with SwiftMailer as shown in this code :

```
$message = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
    ->setSubject('Test')
    ->setTo($user->getEmail())
    ->setFrom($this->from)
    ->setBody(
        $this->twig->render('Emails/event_joined.html.twig', array('user' => $user, 'event' => $event)),
        'text/html'
    )
    ->setContentType("text/html");

    $this->mailer->send($message);
```

I get a "unexpected character error" and the email is not sent.

The 'event_joined.html.twig' template is a copy of another template that works perfectly. Why would this template work in one case and not the other ?

Comment: check the user email or the from

Comment: The user is correct. More informations : I use a twig template formatted as an html doc with <style> tags

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

> $this->twig->disableStrictVariables();

```
$this->twig->disableStrictVariables();
$this->twig->getExtension('core')->setDateFormat('Y/m/d', '%d days');
$message = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
    ->setSubject('Test')
    ->setTo($user->getEmail())
    ->setFrom($this->from)
    ->setBody(
        $this->twig->render('Emails/event_joined.html.twig', array('user' => $user, 'event' => $event)),
        'text/html'
    )
    ->setContentType("text/html");

    $this->mailer->send($message);
```

I hope that work for you ...

Comment: It did'nt work, the error is still : "Unexpected character "'" in Emails/event_joined.html.twig"

Answer (score 0):

I found finaly found the error in my twig template, an unclosed variable was corrupting the twig lexer !